# What are the parameters sent to .always in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't find the documentation on what are the parameters for the [**`always()`**](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) method.

Right now, I'm just using:

```
$.post("foo.do", {
    ...
}, function(data) {
    ...
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    ...
}).always(function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: See also http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ `jqXHR.always(function( data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown ) { });`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation is in [jqXHR section of the $.ajax entry](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR). <sup>**1**</sup>

The parameters are as follows:

**`jqXHR.always(function( data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown ) { });`**

- If an error occurred:

  ```
  jqXHR.always(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { });
  ```
- And otherwise:

  ```
  jqXHR.always(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) { });
  ```

---

*Notes*

1. Thanks to [Mike's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318138/what-are-the-parameters-sent-to-always-in-jquery/26318304#comment41301871_26318138).